# How to determine if value of a given locator in Playwright?

Tags: typescript, playwright

I am very new to writing Playwright tests and I am currently writing a test that will loop through a series of link locators and make sure the links work. My problem comes from some of these links being either the same or sharing very similar names. To fix this I added a unique id value to those specific locators. What I want to do now is every iteration of the loop check the ID value. Is there a built in function or way I can do this?

I have tried using has:page.locator(‘id’) and if (page.locator(‘I’d’) != ‘’) both which obviously didn’t work.

Comment: You can add test IDs to elements and use [`getByTestId`](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-test-id). Also you can generate the test using the [Playwright codegen](https://playwright.dev/docs/codegen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use locator's [getAttribute](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-get-attribute) method in a loop to go over all elements and verify they are not `undefined`.

```
Let value = await locator.getAttribute('Id');
```